# Access SQL Server from node.js on Linux

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, azure-sql-database

How can I connect to SQL Server or SQL Azure from node.js when running on Linux.

The drivers I found on npm all need Windows + VS2005. Is there anyway to access SQL Server from Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working solution, just using '[tedious](https://www.npmjs.org/package/tedious)' directly.

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;

var config = {
    userName: 'myuser@servername',
    password: 'mypassword',
    server: 'servername.database.windows.net',

   // If you're on Windows Azure, you will need this:
   options: {
       encrypt: true
   }
};
var connection = new Connection(config);

connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    if(err)
        console.log(err)
    else
        console.log('works!!!!!')
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The [mssql](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mssql) package in nodejs can adapt to next drivers:

- Tedious by Mike D Pilsbury (pure javascript - windows/osx/linux)
- Microsoft Driver for Node.js for SQL Server by Microsoft Corporation (native - windows only)
- node-tds by Chad Retz (pure javascript -
  windows/osx/linux)

It is stated that [node-tds](https://github.com/cretz/node-tds) and [Tedious](https://github.com/pekim/tedious) both work on linux.

Comment: Tried it, but I can't manage to get a connection, do you have a working example?